# Concatenation in ruby? How can I print a table of 2?

Tags: ruby

I have a question about concatenation. I want to print table of 2.

This program is printing:

```
2
4
6
8
.
.
20 only
```

And I am stuck at concatenation.

Here is the code:

```
x = 0
loop do
    x += 1 #increment of 1
    break if x >= 11
    puts x
end
```

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? You're not concatenating anything there.

Comment: SOrry for that i want the output in the format of 2 X 1 = 2 to 10 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop

```
for i in 1..10 do 
  puts "2 x #{i} = #{ 2*i }"
end
```

`#{ }` is String [interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation)

Comment: Thanks it's working @Santosh can you please suggest me a simple book for ruby beginners

Comment: While it's possible to use `for` loops in Ruby, they're not idiomatic. Instead, use `10.times do |i|` or `1.upto(10) do |i|`.

Comment: @theTinMan thnaks (y) fot the help :)